# arithmetic on pointer to interface which is not a constant size for this architecture

Tags: objective-c, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

I've taken a look at several other questions that all deal with this error, but all of the answers basically just say "don't do pointer math". The code I have is as follows:

```
MyObject * __strong * array = (MyObject * __strong *)calloc(sizeof(MyObject*), 5);
array[0] += 4;
```

I want to know ***why*** I can't do pointer math. According to the error, the `MyObject*` values that are pointed to are of different sizes, but that shouldn't matter, right? It's just an array of pointers - who cares how big the stuff they point to is?

I'm guessing I probably just don't understand all the nuances of ARC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable "array" is a pointer to a pointer and yes, you can consider it as an array of pointers. The size of your object "MyObject" is not constant obviously and the compiler is right not allowing you do such operation.
It is not clear what your wanted to do with your variable.

array[0] += 4;

Takes "MyObject *" from the first element of your array and want to add to it offset of 4, but to calculate such offset compilers wants to know the size of the object.
May be you wanted to do something like

```
    array = array + 4;
or 
    array += 4;
```

Comment: But if I'm allowed to do something like `int* x; x += 4;`, why doesn't that work with `MyObject*`? Does the compiler know that `MyObject*` is an Objective-C object and therefore won't allow me to interpret it as an array?

Comment: @Aderis: Yes, exactly. And, as Serj said, the compiler wouldn't know how much to increment the "raw" pointer by, because it would need to know how big a `MyObject` is and it can't. In your example here, `x += 4` doesn't add 4 to the raw pointer, it adds 4 * `sizeof(int)`. For your original example, `array[0] += 4` would add `4 * sizeof(MyObject)` in earlier versions of the Objective-C runtime, but that's no longer allowed in the modern runtime.

Comment: I just realized my comment was extremely vague. When I mentioned `MyObject*`, I meant as a replacement for the `int`, not for the `int*`.Perhaps this will explain better: I have a pointer to a `MyObject*` value. Since what's being pointed to is a `MyObject*` (which is just the size of a pointer), why can't it my original variable of type MyObject** be incremented?

Comment: @Aderis: What you described is what the expression `array += 4` would do. That's not the expression you wrote. You wrote `array[0] += 4`. `array` is of type `MyObject**`; `array[0]` is of type `MyObject*`, which is an object pointer.

Comment: Oh jeez, I completely misinterpreted my  own code... Thanks for the help.